# How can I add an action to search for the selected Terminal text in Google?

Tags: terminal, search, services

I want to be able to add an action to search Google with any selected text in Terminal. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want the Google search to be via curl in Terminal, or in a browser app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the one that's built into [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/) … (which is a viable replacement for Terminal anyway, if you don't know it yet)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the corresponding service in Preferences/Keyboard.

Default key assignment is <kbd>Shift-Command-L</kbd> which I had to change because it was already used by something else.

After enabling the service you can initiate a Google search in Terminal by selecting a text and

- press the shortcut key
- select the service in the context menu (Services/Search with Google)

Only drawback is that the search always opens Safari even if you have different default browser.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with highlighted text in terminal

Comment: It definitively does for me: highlight/select text, right click, Services.